# Implementing events Spinner with Butter Knife

Tags: android, spinner, butterknife, onitemselectedlistener

First: We need to reference the spinner

```
@Bind(R.id.field_type_id)
Spinner mTypeIdSpinner;
```

Second: Create string array

```
<string-array name="type_id_array">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
    <item>Five</item>
</string-array>
```

Third: Load the adapter in your activity (onCreate method for example)

```
private void loadSpinnerIdTypes() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.type_id_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mTypeIdSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Fourth: Listen the events

```
@OnItemSelected(R.id.field_type_id)
void onItemSelected(int position) {
    Timber.d("Element selected %s ", mTypeIdSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position));
}
```

Answer (score 41):

You can use `@OnItemSelected` with method arguments `Spinner` and `int` see example:

```
@OnItemSelected(R.id.my_spinner)
public void spinnerItemSelected(Spinner spinner, int position) {
    // code here
}
```

(works with ButterKnife v. 7.0.1)

Comment: Also works with ButterKnife v6.1.0 (just confirmed with a test in my device)